# how to do the animate the uiimageview and stop the remaining process

Tags: ios, iphone

I am doing one application.In that i am doing the animation for uiimageview to show the different image like below

```
    UIImageView * fearthersanimate = nil;
    [fearthersanimate setCenter:sender.center];

    fearthersanimate = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120,200)];
    [fearthersanimate setCenter:CGPointMake(sender.center.x, sender.center.y)];
    fearthersanimate .animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"water_can_1.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"water_can_2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"water_can_3.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"water_can_4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"water_can_5.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"water_can_6.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"water_can_7.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"water_can_8.png"],
                                         nil];
    fearthersanimate.animationDuration =  1.0f;
    fearthersanimate.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [self.view addSubview: fearthersanimate];
    [fearthersanimate startAnimating];
```

But remaining operation is starting before end of this animation.But i need to do this animation first and until i need to stop the remaining process.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your rest of operation in other method and call it after the same delay as you set animation time for images.
Below is the line of code by which you can call other method after some time interval

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(restOfOperations) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

//restOfOperations  method defination/implementation

```
  -(void)restOfOperations
  {
    //your code you want to perform after image animation
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UIView animation block. For example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

Put the remaining process in the completion block.

Answer (score 0):

Those animations are performed asynchronously, so you just need to fight async with async.

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(feathersanimate.animationDuration * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // Remaining logic
});
```